# Attempting Firebase auth (with Google) on Android Wear 2.0 shows "InternalFirebaseAuth.FIREBASE_AUTH_API is not available on this device"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, wear-os

I am trying to use Firebase Auth (10.0.1, Google as auth provider) with Android Wear 2.0, but when I run **signInWithCredential**, operation fails (see this logs below.) I am using this [method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin).

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseApiNotAvailableException: API: InternalFirebaseAuth.FIREBASE_AUTH_API is not available on this device.
                                                                              at com.google.firebase.zza.zzz(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzq$zzd.zzy(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaap$zza.zzC(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaap$zza.onConnectionFailed(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaap$zzb$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I have been successful using Firebase Real Time DB with Wear 1.0 and 2.0, but auth is not cooperating. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I notice you asked this same question on the Wear developer community on G+, and got the answer there: Firebase Auth is not yet supported on Wear. https://plus.google.com/+LewisMcGeary/posts/BQzGE2G4RX6

Comment: ​ Thanks! Good to know. Are there any good workarounds? I'm using the Firebase UID to key data nodes with realtime database,  maybe I should use the Google account ID instead, and use plain Google auth on wear. Thoughts?

Comment: When it will be available, any news?